# How to hide parts of text with Bootstrap only for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table where one column only contains datetime's. I want to hide the date and only show the time on mobile devices (with Bootstrap). I have found the class `visible-lg` and tried to do it with `<span>`'s.

**But why aren't they on the same line?**

[image]

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Value A</th>
            <th>Value B</th>
            <th>Value C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-timestamp="1390158176">
            <td><span class="visible-lg">01.19.14</span><span>20:02:56</span></td>
            <td>22.5</td>
            <td>950.91</td>
            <td>531.66</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tried putting these two `<span>`'s in one `<span>` that is in the `<td>`. I also tried putting the time with out a span after the span into the `<td>`. I want them on the same line. A wide-screen-user shouldn't notice that the date would be hidden if he shows the page on a small browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To hide the date and only show the time on mobile devices use the class [hidden-xs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities):

```
<td><span class="hidden-xs">01.19.14</span><span>20:02:56</span></td>
```

When the `.hidden-xs` style is applied you will notice that the bootstrap.css sets its display to block causing the `span` tags to take up the entire width of the column.  Although not generally recommended, the only option I see (beside using an additional media query) is fighting fire with fire and using `!important` within your own subclass.

**HTML**

```
<td><span class="hidden-xs hidden-xs-inline">01.19.14</span><span> 20:02:56</span></td>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden-xs-inline{
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3e6dz/